# Another IndexError with python

Tags: python, random

This is supposed to become a random name generator in the end, all the random part is working. Only problem is that it is REALLY random, getting weird stuff like aaaaaaaa etc.
So I'm trying to add a rule to **not** allow 2 vowels after each other (same goes with consonants).

So yeah, guys please help me out here. I've been looking throu' this code for 2 hours now and I cant find the problem. 
Just pasting my entire code here.

```
import random
import string
import numpy as np
from sys import argv
import csv
# abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
# Example output: floke fl0ke flok3 fl0k3
#


class facts:
    kons = list('bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz') #20
    voks = list('aeiouy') #6
    abc = list('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')

def r_trfa(): #True Or False (1/0)
    x = random.randrange(0, 2)
    return x;

def r_kons(): #Konsonant
    y = random.randrange(0, 20)
    x = facts.kons[y]
    return x;

def r_vok(): #Vokal
    y = random.randrange(0, 6)
    x = facts.voks[y]
    return x;

def r_len(): #Langd
    x = random.randrange(4, 8)
    return x;

def r_type():
    x = random.randrange(1, 4)
    return x;

def r_structure(length): #Skapar strukturen
    y = r_type()
    if y == 0:
        no1 = 1
    else:
        no1 = 2
    i = 0
    x = [no1]
    y = r_type()
    if not no1 == y:
        x.append(y)
    while i < length:
        y = r_type()
        if not x[i] == y:
            x.append(y)
        i = i + 1
    x2 = list(x)
    return x2;


def name(): #Final product
    struct = r_structure(r_len())
    name = struct
```

Comment: If you're getting stuff like `aaaaa`, that means you almost certainly have a bug.

Comment: What are you trying to do here?

Comment: Sample input and output, please. If you do this, you'll probably end up with some doc strings, too. Which is a Good Thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got several bugs. For example, you're checking the value `y` against 0 even though it is always in the range 1-4, probably unintended behavior. Furthermore, you never actually call a function that gets you a character, and you never create a string. Thus it's not clear what you're trying to do.

Here's how I'd rewrite things based on my guess of what you want to do.

```
import random, itertools

voks = frozenset('aeiouy')
abc = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'

def r_gen():
    last=None #both classes ok
    while 1:
        new = random.choice(abc)
        if (new in voks) != last:
            yield new
            last = (new in voks)

def name(): #Final product
    length = random.randrange(4, 8)
    return ''.join(itertools.islice(r_gen(), length))
```

Comment: You shouldn't encourage OP to use a German word for `vowel` as a variable name.

Comment: Woaw, thanks, this code actually worked like a charm! 
@Droogans Its short and understandable, so why not? :D

Comment: Look up [Section 5.2 on the GNU Coding Standard](https://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/standards.html#Comments): *Please write the comments in a GNU program in English, because English is the one language that nearly all programmers in all countries can read. If you do not write English well, please write comments in English as well as you can, then ask other people to help rewrite them. If you can’t write comments in English, please find someone to work with you and translate your comments into English.* It's considered good practice, even for non-GNU programs.

Comment: And here's a snippet from [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#encodings-pep-263): *All identifiers in the Python standard library MUST use ASCII-only identifiers, and SHOULD use English words wherever feasible (in many cases, abbreviations and technical terms are used which aren't English). In addition, string literals and comments must also be in ASCII. The only exceptions are (a) test cases testing the non-ASCII features, and (b) names of authors.* ... *Open source projects with a global audience are encouraged to adopt a similar policy.*

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're having is that your loop increments `i` always, but only adds an additional value to your `x` list if the random value doesn't match `x[i]`. This means that if you get several matches in a row, `i` may become larger than the largest index into `x` and so you'll get an `IndexError` exception.

I'm not entirely sure I understand what you're trying to do, but I think this will do something similar to your current `r_structure` function:

```
def r_structure(length):
    """Returns a list of random "types", avoiding any immediate repeats"""
    x = [r_type()]
    while len(x) < length:
        y = r_type()
        if y != x[-1]: # check against the last item in the list
            x.append(y)
    return x
```

If your goal is simply to randomly generate a sequence of alternating vowels and consonants, there's an easier way than what you seem to be doing. First off, you can use `random.choice` to pick your characters. Further, rather than picking many letters and rejecting ones that are of the wrong type, you can simply pick from one string, then pick from the other, for as long as you need:

```
import random

def alternating_characters(length):
    characters = ["aeiouy", "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz"]
    char_type = random.randrange(2) # pick a random letter type to start with
    results = []

    while len(char_list) < length:
        results.append(random.choice(characters[char_type])) # pick random char
        char_type = 1-char_type # pick from the other list next time

    return "".join(char_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well it's unclear what you want to do.. As the conditions on vowels and consonants is the same, so why do you need to differentiate between them?

So all you need to do is take a random letter and check that it doesn't match with the last letter. 
Here's some code:

```
import random

abc = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
def gen_word(length):
    last = ''
    while length > 0:
        l = random.choice(abc)
        if l != last:
            length -= 1
            yield l

if __name__ == '__main__':
    word = ''.join(gen_word(10))
    print word
```